# Concepts-Lite iterator comparison compares values

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-concepts

I've been racking my brain on this one for a few months on and off. I have defined a set of concepts which loosely describe containers and predicates.

In general, I'm looping over the container using an old-fashioned `for` loop and comparing equality of a parameter iterator to the `end(container)` iterator. What I can't figure out is why this won't compile when given a `Container<T>` such that `T` does not have an equality comparer (`T::operator==(T other)`)

These concepts are by no means complete, and are simply for learning purposes, there are no doubt other ways to accomplish what I'm doing.

The problem code is in this short function defined in "queryalgorithms.h":

```
#pragma once

#include <algorithm>
#include "concepts.h"

template<typename C, typename P, typename V = typename C::value_type, typename I = typename C::iterator>
I last(C & collection, I iterator, P predicate) requires Container<C> && Predicate<P, V> && Incrementable<I> {
    I out;
    for (iterator; iterator != end(collection); iterator++) {
    }

    return out;
}
```

The test code which fails is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <forward_list>

#include "queryalgorithms.h"

using namespace std;

class MyClass {
    public:
        int value;

        MyClass(int v): value(v) {};
};

template <typename T>
void Test() {
    auto collection = T();
    for (auto i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        last(collection, begin(collection), [] (auto x) { return true; });
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    Test<vector<MyClass>>();
    return 0;
}
```

Not sure if this is much help, but for completeness the concepts.h file is [here](https://pastebin.com/ciTZtjsF). It's a lot and I don't feel it adds much value so I put that on pastebin.

As described above the small example only compiles for types which have an equality comparer defined (e.g. `Test<vector<int>>()` will work fine). And the compiler error from g++ is as follows:

```
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:800:22: error: no match 
for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘const MyClass’ and ‘const MyClass’)
  if (!(*__first1 == *__first2))
```

So my question is, why is the compiler deducing the types of `iterator != end(collection)` to be the value type `V` rather than the iterator type `I`?

**Edit**: I'm compiling using `g++ -fconcepts --std=c++17 -o test test.cc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Container<T>` requires `EqualityComparable<T>` which requires `a == b` for lvalues `a` and `b` of type `T`. The C++ standard says that `a == b` for a container requires its value type to be `EqualityComparable` ([N4659 [container.requirements.general] Table 83](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.general#4.sentence-82)). 
Checking `Container<vector<MyClass>>` in the requires clause on `last` instantiates `vector`'s `==` operator, which is most likely implemented in terms of `std::equal`, which I speculate is the algorithm being defined on line 800 of `stl_algobase.h`.

Since `MyClass` is not `EqualityComparable`, `vector<MyClass>` does not model `Container`. The standard notably does not require `vector`'s (or any container's) `operator==` to be constrained, so you get a hard error checking the constraints instead of `last` SFINAE-ing away and removing itself from overload resolution.

Comment: Admittedly I messed up my definition of `Container<T>` with respect to the standard you quoted, so thank you for that. My definition of `Container<T>` (note it is a custom definition) required the `Container<T>` itself to be `EqualityComparable` rather than the `Container::value_type`. Adjusting to the correct definition of `EqualityComparable` for `Container` leaves a much shorter error as you have specified in your answer. However, I don't think this answers the original question as stated

Comment: Change this clause: "the requires clause on last instantiates vector's assignment operator..." to "...instantiates vector's equality operator.." and I'll accept this answer. The problem was due to my messed up definition of `EqualityComparable` for `Container` instead of its value type. Thanks

Comment: Woops, huge thinko there.